# Expat returning to UK - Driving Licence

Tags: driving

I'm a British Citizen with UK passport returning to UK after being in the EU for 7 years. 
Can I apply for a change of address on driving licence straight away, or  am I under the 185 day rule?
Thank you

Comment: is your driving licence a UK one, or an (other) EU one?

Comment: EU one, I would like to change back to an UK one

Answer (score 1):

According to gov.uk, yo have to wait the 185 days.

https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence

Click "Start now" and the first page clarifies it.

Comment: Then what happens after 185 daysphilip

Comment: I don’t think this answer is correct. The gov.uk page says ‘ You’re normally a resident if you live in Great Britain for 185 days in each calendar year.’ Nowhere does it say you must wait 185 days **before** applying. I very much doubt a British citizen who passed their driving test in the UK and has moved back to live permanently in the UK needs to wait.